# css transition works in an element but not in a second element

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to build a simple image slider with css and javascript, I have an UL with some LI inside. the images are LI's backgrounds so I just have to move two LI, the active one and the next one, to make the slider work.
When the "next" button is pressed I add classes to the two LI and what happen is that the already visible li perform his transition disappearing on the left but the second LI snaps in position without sliding in from the right. I can't understand where i go wrong and why the second LI doesn't trigger the transition.

Here is a pen with some code:
https://codepen.io/luzzuc/pen/xONywP

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="active" style="background-image: url(http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/26/9780-itsahim.JPG)"></li>
  <li style="background-image: url(http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/5/5b/NSMBDIY_Mario_Jump.png/revision/latest?cb=20100405031309)"></li>
</ul>
<br><br>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 12%;
  position: relative;
  background: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 60%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.active-slide {
  left: -100%;
}

.next {
  left: 100%;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: left 2s;
}

.next-slide {
  left: 0;
}
```

Javascript

```
var b = document.getElementById('next');
b.addEventListener('click', animate);

function animate() {
  var a = document.querySelector('.active');
  var b = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];
  b.classList.add('next');
  a.classList.add('active-slide');
  b.classList.add('next-slide');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try this version: https://jsfiddle.net/urhn8b6k/

First of all, the initial status of the 2nd `li` is `left: 0;` and the css indicated that from `left: 0;` to `left: 100%;` with `transition: left 2s;` in `.next`, so you have to move `transition: left 2s;` to `.next-slide`

While doing b.addClass... a.addClass... b.addClass... that's simply doing b.addClass("next next-slide"), try put the second addClass into a `setTimeout` with delay 1ms should solve the problem

Comment: I tried to add both next and next-slide classes together but nothing happen. Probably the `setTimeout` is a solution but I found a way do make it work without it and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

obviously once posted the question I found the solution. It turns out that to trigger the second transition a browser redraw is necessary. in order to make the browser to redraw the page a simple operation in an element is enough so I simply ask for offsetHeight of the element ad so the code that was:

```
b.classList.add('next');
a.classList.add('active-slide');
b.classList.add('next-slide');
```

became:

```
b.classList.add('next');
a.classList.add('active-slide');
var f = b.offsetHeight;
b.classList.add('next-slide');
```

and everything works fine